# C "->" (Arrow Operator) Seg Fault with Simply Structure

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I just started learning C about a week ago and Im having some issues using the arrow operator "->".  I tried looking up examples online but nothing seemd to help.  Here is the simple program.

```
struct foo
{
    int x;
};

main(){
    struct foo t;
    struct foo* pt;

    t.x = 1;
    pt->x = 2; //here
}
```

when I compile this with gcc -o structTest structTest.c, and run it, I always get a segmentation fault on line I marked with the comment "here".  Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: I like your username. It's... straightforward.

Comment: You should never dereference: uninitialized pointers, `NULL` pointers,  and pointers that have been freed. `pt->x` is the same as `(*pt).x`.

Comment: As you have mentioned you are using `gcc`, I will suggest you to compile your code always with `Wall` and `g` option, like,  `gcc -g -Wall -o output filename.c` . With `Wall`, even before you execute your code (which you obviously can't, if you haven't fixed the warnings), you will find and easily solve most of your problems, which otherwise might end up like this. `g` helps if you would like to debug your program later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize `pt` to point to something! Right now it's just a <strike>null</strike> undefined pointer.

Try:

```
pt = &t;
```

for example.

Comment: it is not null pointer. the value of uninitialised pointer is undefined.

Comment: `Right now it's just a null pointer` no right now `pt` is just garbage,   uninitialised variable  initialized by garbage value in C

Comment: Not necessarily null.  You can never trust that a freshly declared variable is set to anything.  It's a pointer to SOMETHING, but something that doesn't belong to you.

Answer (score 3):

`pt` is never initialized.

Try adding  `pt = &t;`

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to de-reference a pointer that hasn't been initialized (to point to something that you have access to).

```
struct foo
{
    int x;
};

main(){
    struct foo t; // this is an instance of foo
    struct foo* pt; // this is a pointer to a foo

    t.x = 1; // you can set the contents of foo
    pt->x = 2; // you can't de-reference an un-initialized pointer
}
```

To fix the problem:

```
struct foo
{
    int x;
};

main(){
    struct foo t;
    struct foo* pt;

    t.x = 1;
    pt = &t; // make your pointer point to an instance of foo
    pt->x = 2; // this is ok now (this modifies the contents of 't')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to think of a pointer as a kind of two part thing. The first part is the pointer itself:

```
struct foo* pt;
```

The other part of the pointer is the thing it is pointing to. The problem with your code above is that your pointer isn't pointing to anything.

The way you make a pointer point to something is by initializing it. There are a few ways to do this. Your pointer always has to point to a valid instance of the target type of the pointer before you can dereference it (use the -> or * operators).

```
pt = new foo(); // one way to initialize your pointer by pointing it to newly allocated dynamic memory
pt = &t; // another way, by pointing it to the address of a local variable

void bar(foo *x)
{
    pt = x; // another way, by assigning it to another pointer
}

bar(new foo());
```

Before you have initialized your pointer, it is left dangling (a "dangling pointer"). You can't dereference it because it's not pointing at anything valid. Usually if you do this, your program crashes, but it can have any number of other interesting behaviours.

To fix your program, you have to make `pt` point at something valid. I don't know what your end goal for your program is, so you would have to decide that, but hopefully I've given enough clues.